# Conditional excel number and formula formatting based on the previous two cells

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet that looks something like this:

[Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uj06H.png)

What I want to do here is to do some kind of conditional number formatting, like if I put an item that is counted by the hour like the 'something hourly' row along with the starting and the ending time , the duration column (d2) will be formatted as a time duration in h:mm and will be calculated accordingly.

On the other hand if I put something like an one-time payment and puts time starts and time ends as a hyphen, then the cell (D3) will be formatted as a regular number, so that it can be multiplied with the price per unit altogether.

To make it simple:
A2 (time-based) -> Enters starting and ending time, then D2 will calculate the time duration, and the amount (F2) will be calculated by the duration using the formula (F2*D2*24)

A3 (unit-based) -> Types starting and ending time as a hyphen, treats D3 as a normal number, then F3 will be multiply E3 by D3.

Comment: I did used the custom excel formatting highlighted here, but I'm not too sure how to use it conditionally:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-or-delete-a-custom-number-format-78f2a361-936b-4c03-8772-09fab54be7f4

https://exceloffthegrid.com/change-number-format-based-on-its-value/

Comment: BTW, I'm on Excel 2013.